# Calculation of distance while switching between two speeds

Tags: mathematics, movement

There are two speed values, that are used by moving object. After a while speed switching occurs from V1 to V2. I need the formula that can be used for calculation of current distance (at specified time).

Input variable:

- T - Current time

Constants:

- V1 - first speed
- V2 - second speed
- Ts - switching time between V1 and V2
- P - switching power

Output variable:

- S = ?

I tried to use next formula:
`S = Lerp[Clamp(T / Ts, 0, 1) ^ P), V1, V2] * T`

But in this case the moving object will be returned back after time and moves forward again.

Probably acceleration should be used in the formula?

Comment: Explain switching power. This is more a math question than a coding or gamedev question. I see it this way: you have V1 and V2, and V1 is constant until Ts (an horizon) is reached. Then V2 is constant too from that point. What is P?

Comment: P is how fast switching will be occurred. In my example formula it's interpolation alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting your speed transition formula as

```
float blend = clamp((currentTime - startTime)/transitionDuration), 0, 1);

Vector3 currentVelocity = startVelocity + (endVelocity - startVelocity) * blend;
```

Then during the transition we're applying a constant acceleration of:

```
Vector3 acceleration = (endVelocity - startVelocity) / transitionDuration;
```

Now we can integrate this to get the total displacement from the starting position at time T=0 in three parts.

**First**, for `currentTime <= startTime`,

```
Vector3 currentPosition= startPosition + startVelocity * currentTime;
```

Which at the end of this interval reaches a value of:

```
Vector3 accelerationStartPosition = startPosition + startVelocity * startTime;
```

**Second**, for `startTime < currentTime <= startTime + transitionDuration`, we can use the formula for position under constant acceleration:

$$\vec p(\Delta t) = \vec p_0 + \vec v_0 \cdot \Delta t + \frac 1 2 \vec a \cdot \Delta t^2$$

in code:

```
float transitionTime = currentTime - startTime;

currentPosition = accelerationStartPosition
             + startVelocity * transitionTime 
             + 0.5f * acceleration * transitionTime*transitionTime;
```

Which we can simplify to:

```
 currentPosition = startPosition + startVelocity * currentTime
            + 0.5f * acceleration * transitionTime*transitionTime;
```

Which again, at the end of the transition interval, takes a value of:

```
float endTime = startTime + transitionDuration;

Vector3 transitionEndPosition = startPosition
               + startVelocity * endTime
               + 0.5f * acceleration * transitionDuration*transitionDuration;
```

**And lastly**, for `currentTime > startTime + transitionDuration`:

```
currentPosition = transitionEndPosition + endVelocity * (currentTime - endTime);
```